# Modify all items of a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I need to iterate through all items in a DynamoDB table with sort key as "default" and add the same 2 attributes(Maps of String) to all of them. This is to basically backfill data with a default values. Can this be achieved using Boto3?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be achieved by scanning through the entire dB and filtering the sort key with default. check the below link and then use update_item to update each one them or batch update if you want to reduce number of calls

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html#GettingStarted.Python.04.Scan